# Triggering more then 1 rules in DROOLS DRL File

Tags: drools

I have a drl file containing 10 rules. Each has a condition like -

```
Rule 1 
when 
      field1 == "X"
then
      status == "A"

Rule 2
when 
      field1 == "Y"
then
      status == "A"
```

So as seen based on value of variable `field1` rules are to be executed.

Now I have a object containing more then 1 value like List. So if the List contains both values X & Y, only Rule 1 is applied and then processing is stopped. Rule 2 is never triggered.

Is there any way I can ask DROOLS to continue applying Rules even if 1 rule is successful ?

Comment: This isn't the way Drools rules are written in DRL. Rules matching multiple values in a `List<X>` need to be written against a List object on the left hand side. And right hand side contains Java statements, which is not what you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `fireAllRules();` available in Drools session.

It provides you following variances:

```
        fireAllRules();
        fireAllRules(AgendaFilter agendaFilter) 
        fireAllRules(AgendaFilter agendaFilter, int max)
        fireAllRules(int max)
```

In last two variances, `max` is the upper limit on the rules to be fired. In your example, if you use max as `10`, it can fire all 10 rules provided they meet the criteria.

**Please Note**: The rules should be configured in such a way that they qualify for execution based on the updated state. Request you to review the `criteria` fragment (the `when` clause of the rules and ensure that they  indeed result into positive evaluation during execution.

e.g. if rules are written like below:

```
Rule 1 
when 
  field1 == "X"
then
  status == "A"

Rule 2
when 
  field1 == "Y"
then
  status == "A"
```

then either `field1 == "X"` is true or `field1 == "Y"` is true and thus will trigger one rule at `MAX`.

But if we write the rules like

```
Rule 1 
when 
  field1 == "X" || field1 == "Y" 
then
  status == "A"

Rule 2
when 
  field1 == "X" || field1 == "Y" 
then
  status == "A"
```

then both the rules i.e. `Rule 1` and `Rule 2` will qualify if `field1` is `X` or `Y`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't going to help unless OP has called fireAllRules(1) for which there is no indication at all. I don't know why this was accepted but it just doesn't fit the question.

Comment: @laune: OP is interested in knowing a mechanism to fire more than one rule. `fireAllRules()` is the mechanism, which helps in achieving the same. I think that is the reason, it was accepted as it served the purpose. I am not sure, what is the concern/confusion here??

Comment: OP must have called fireAllRules - otherwise nothing at all would have happened. It seems OP just doesn't know how to write rules testing for values in a List.

Comment: @laune: There could be difference in opinion/perception. This answer addresses the question `how to fire more than one matching rule?`. Since OP has accepted the answer, it's safe to assume, this was the primary concern, which was addressed. Please feel free to post a better answer, if available. If OP finds the new answer better, he/she may probably refuse this one and accept the new answer.

Comment: I'm not sure at all what triggered OPs question. Anyway, I've added another answer.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of writing a rule that matches a String field (called `field`) in a class Type is

```
rule "match field"
when
    Type( field == "X" )
then
    //...
end
```

You can write another rule where you match against `"Y"`, which is indicated if you need to do something else. If you want to do the same, you can write a slightly more complex test:

```
rule "match field"
when
    Type( field == "X" || == "Y" )
then
    //...
end
```

(Yes, this unusual syntax is permitted in Drools' DRL language.)

To test for a value contained in a List, you can write

```
rule "match list element"
when
    List( this contains "X" )
then
    //...
end
```

Again, you can write another rule where you test for `contains "Y"`, and it will fire, too, as long as the `List<String>` contains `"X"` and `"Y"`.

A bare List as a fact in Working Memory is usually not a good idea. But if a class member is a List, a similar form can be used:

```
rule "match value in list member"
when
    Type( list contains "X" )
then
    //...
end
```

There is no need for special precaution to be taken for more than one rule firing. The standard activation `session.fireAllRules()` fires until all activations have been processed.

Some rule attributes may have the effect of terminating the processing of activations prematurely - use them cautiously.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to give you a bit of a different answer because I don't know what drools is but I can tell you how we do this in other languages. Basically it requires a string builder concept and some logic touch point changes.

**Set your string:**

`string yourLongerStatusStringSetter = '';`

**Work through your checking and append your string:**

Rule 1 `when field1 == "X" then yourLongerStatusStringSetter &= "Meets Status A criteria."`

Rule 2 `when field1 == "Y" then yourLongerStatusStringSetter &= " Meets Status B criteria."`

Continue rules and checks and appending (provided criteria is met)

**Output your 'statuses':**

`howeverYouWriteYourOutput( yourLongerStatusStringSetter )`

**Which will print to the screen:**

`Meets Status A criteria. Meets Status B criteria`

Just food for thought on an alternate approach.

Comment: Sorry, but this is way off the mark. Drools works fundamentally different, so how-tos from a procedural language aren't helpful.

Comment: Sure no problem...(and yes I am a procedural programmer interesting you picked that up) :)

Comment: If you want to, I can post a link to "rule based programming for JAva programmers".

Comment: @laune Absolutely...I would appreciate that.